# Error in match.arg(opt.crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r, math, stat

I have an code but it have an error In R, I do not know how to run it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWFgl.png)
And here should be run out like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZzEB.png)

```
library(forecast)
library(itsmr)
tor = readRDS ("/Users/zehaoli/Desktop/TorontoWeather.rds")
row <- 1:length(tor[, 1])

tempMay1.7 <- subset(tor, tor$Date.Time >= "2003-05-01 00:00" &
                       tor$Date.Time <= "2003-05-07 23:00")$Temp
tempMay8 <- subset(tor, tor$Date.Time >= "2003-05-08 00:00" &
                     tor$Date.Time <= "2003-05-08 23:00") $Temp

M <-c("season",24,"trend",2) 
tesname <-Resid(tempMay1.7,M) 
a <-arma(tesname,1,1) 
f<-forecast(tempMay1.7,M,a,h=24,opt=0)

Error in match.arg(opt.crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

plot(1:192,c(tempMay1.7,rep(NA,24)),
     type="l",col="blue",ylim=c(3,22),ylab="Temp(°C)",
     xlab="Date",main="Toronto Temperature (May 1 - May 8,2003)",
     xaxt="n")
axis(side=1,at=12+(0:7)*24,
     labels=c("May1","May2","May3","May4","May5","Мау6","May?","Ma8"))

lines(169:192,f$pred,col="red")
lines(169:192,f$l,lty=2,col="green")
lines(169:192,f$u,lty=2,col="green")
lines(169:192,tempMay8,col="black")
```

Error in match.arg(opt.crit) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Comment: Try this: Remove `opt = 0` ->`f <- forecast(tempMay1.7, M, a, h=24)`

Comment: Remove opt = 0 ->f <- forecast(tempMay1.7, M, a, h=24) will be 
Error in if (fan) { : the condition has length > 1